# Getting TypeError: expected a character buffer object for a pandas.dataframe.replace call?

Tags: python, pandas, character-encoding, pygsheets

I'm building an interface between python and Google sheets using python2.7 & pygsheets:

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tracker.py", line 108, in <module>
    test.track()
  File "Tracker.py", line 99, in track
    self.sheet.set_dataframe(json.dumps(pd.DataFrame(list(cursor.fetchall())),default=iterencode),self.anchor,copy_index=False, copy_head=True, fit=False, escape_formulae=False,nan=str('\n'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygsheets/worksheet.py", line 742, in set_dataframe
    df = df.replace(pd.np.nan, nan)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

I've tried nan='NaN', '\n' as well as 0- however everything comes back with the same error.

The error is entirely within this line:

```
self.sheet.set_dataframe(json.dumps(pd.DataFrame(list(cursor.fetchall())),default=iterencode),self.anchor,copy_index=False, copy_head=True, fit=False, escape_formulae=False,nan=str('NanN'))
```

and actually is in the last arg: `nan=str('NaN')`

I've checked pandas documentation for replace:

```
value : scalar, dict, list, str, regex, default None

Value to use to fill holes (e.g. 0), alternately a dict of values specifying which value to use for each column (columns not in the dict will not be filled). Regular expressions, strings and lists or dicts of such objects are also allowed.
```

which also seems more or less in line.

pygsheets/worksheet.py also doesn't have anything else apart from that one line: `df = df.replace(pd.np.nan, nan)` & nan being the unaltered input that I send i.e., `str('NaN')`.

I'm wondering what this means- is this a versioning issue with some python or library version not matching ? or something else?

I hacked my way through this by printing to a csv file and then reading that as a dataframe and passing that into the function because I didn't find a solution in time.

However I'd still like to understand how and why and where does this problem arise ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to replace all NaNs by another value, why not use `df.fillna(newValue)`?

Comment: with reference to the `set_dataframe` code in your question - what happens if you skip `nan=str('NanN')` but instead append `.fillna("NaN")` (or whatever else you want the nans to replaced by) to `pd.DataFrame(...)` ie `pd.DataFrame(...).fillna('NanN')... `